# Way to insert rows of output into a table?

Tags: sql, insert

I was just wondering if there was a way to *Insert* *rows* and *columns* into a *table* based on a previous `query`.  I don't know if I'm explaining it right so let me try and show you

Below is a simple *Outer Join* which shows what is missing from the `EMPHIREINFO` table:

```
Select b.empno, b.empstate, c.startdt, c.enddt, c.cntrlgth
From EMPADDRESS b Left Outer Join EMPHIREINFO c
On b.empno = c.empno
Order By startdt
```

Output:

```
EMPNO   EMPSTATE    STARTDT     ENDDT       CNTRLGTH
9873    NY          20-MAY-11   20-NOV-11   6
7566    CA          15-OCT-11   15-OCT-12   12
7499    MN          31-OCT-11   30-APR-12   6
7369    NJ          15-JAN-12   15-JAN-13   12
5300    NY          11-AUG-12   11-AUG-13   12
7521    NJ          12-NOV-12   12-MAY-13   6
4600    NY          10-DEC-12   10-JUN-13   6
7902    CA          
7934    NY          
7900    MN
```

All of the empty spots are `(null)`, which I assume you knew but wanted to mention none-the-less.  Anyway, I was wondering if there was a way to *Insert* the `EMPNO` and `EMPSTATE` from `EMPADDRESS` into `EMPHIREINFO` based on this output.  I know I can manually just do an *Insert Statement*, but I am thinking of a situation down the road where I am not dealing with a *table* that has 10 rows, but thousands.

I did do some research prior to coming here, but Google and even searching on this website left me empty handed.  Any help, as usual, is welcomed.

Comment: I'm not clear on how you want to insert records from `EMPADDRESS` into `EMPHIREINFO`... from your question, it looks like the two tables have totally different columns... so what data from the source table do you want to put from the source into the destination?

Comment: Since the `EMPNO`s (and `EMPNAMES` which arent shown) are going to be the same in each `table` I wanted to `Insert` the ones I was missing.  When I was originally messing around with `EMPHIREINFO` I only added 7 people, I now wanted to add the rest of them but doing 10 `Insert` statements didnt seem appetizing, and I wanted to learn a new trick for the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL allows you to insert into a table using the form

```
insert into table1
select ...
```

as long as the column number and types align. If they don't, you can specify the insert columns, eg

```
insert into table1 (col1, col5, col2)
select ...
```

So, for you (assuming the column types align):

```
insert into EMPHIREINFO 
Select b.empno, b.empstate, c.startdt, c.enddt, c.cntrlgth
From EMPADDRESS b Left Outer Join EMPHIREINFO c
On b.empno = c.empno
Order By startdt
```

You may need to specify columns though, for example if you have an autoincrementing id column (which is common)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the quick response.  This is exactly what I was hoping I can do.

Comment: In case you wanted to know what I did to get the missing rows inserted, I had to do this:
    Insert Into EMPHIREINFO(empno, empname, startdt, enddt, cntrlgth)
    Select b.empno, b.empname, c.startdt, c.enddt, c.cntrlgth
    From EMPADDRESS b Left Outer Join EMPHIREINFO c
    On b.empno = c.empno
    Where c.startdt Is Null
    And c.enddt Is Null
    And c.cntrlgth Is Null

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT destination_table (column1, column2,column3)
SELECT a.column1, a.column2, b.column3
FROM source_table_a AS a
INNER JOIN source_table_b AS b ON (a.key1 = b.key1)
```

You can use this INSERT syntax with other commands that produce a result set:

```
INSERT destination_table (column1, column2,column3)
EXEC usp_produce_some_output
```